# how to set background task in a android app?

Tags: android

I need to set a background task when the app is in background.I  am setting notification from the app itself.So,when the app is closed,app need to receive
notification.

Answer (score -1):

You can start your background task from `onPause` or on`onStop`.

Take a look at this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html) from the docs. It says

> When the system calls onPause() for your activity, it technically means your activity is still partially visible, but most often is an indication that the user is leaving the activity and it will soon enter the Stopped state.
>
> When your activity receives a call to the onStop() method, it's no longer visible and should release almost all resources that aren't needed while the user is not using it. Once your activity is stopped, the system might destroy the instance if it needs to recover system memory. In extreme cases, the system might simply kill your app process without calling the activity's final onDestroy() callback, so it's important you use onStop() to release resources that might leak memory.